# What is a sibling that comes long after all the other siblings called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I belive there's a word for this, as I've heard it before, but I can't think of it. If a sibling comes many years after the rest of the pack, what is set sibling called? It doesn't need to be one word, but just something you can call someone.

If this helps, I've heard siblings like that are a product of the mother missing having young kids around, due to only having older children, hence having one many years later.

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard of a 'caboose baby'.

Comment: How was I supposed to know there was a similar question to mine? It's on another site, meaning when I wrote my question title I could only see questions asked on this site. Not any other site. Also, the answer on that site doesen't really answer my question very well. Nigel's caboose baby did though, so thanks Nigel J. @k1eran

Comment: @A.Kvåle my intention was to help you by referencing a very similar question with some reasonable answers including the *caboose baby* one. If there is a significant difference between what you need and the ELL question can you edit your question and I’ll remove my close-vote.

Comment: @k1eran closing somebody's question because it may or may not have an answer on a *sister-site* is not the fault of the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA & a-kvåle : I have now read the meta post at https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11322/131620 and I see 18 votes saying ELU questions are standalone and zero saying OP should check ELL. I was over zealous here with the close vote referencing ELL as a duplicate, so I'll retract it and add a comment below instead. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: A ELL question which may be relevant is https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/114307/43624

Answer (score -1):

In my family we refer to him or her as an *accident* -- though not in front of the parents.

That's a tongue-in-cheek term, of course, and if you're trying to accurately describe someone rather than make a joke, it's probably not applicable.

Comment: Well, the term I'm looking for is one describing a child that's born a long time after the other children. Whether they're an accident or not is irrelevant, though there's probably a correlation between the two, as parents usually dont intentionally have a child so long after the others.

Comment: these days we say "second marriage"